# How can increasing the wait states increases the speed of Processor?

Tags: microcontroller

I saw in a datasheet where for 0 wait states the Max speed is 30MHz and 1 wait state the speed could go up to 60MHz. My understanding is as you add the wait states the speed comes down as the processor waits for the data.

Comment: I think you should look at the statement in a different way. It can be rearranged to say: Increasing the clock speed of a processor will often increase the overall processing speed EVEN if you have to increase the number of wait states at the memory interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait states are extra cycles that the memory interface waits between accesses.  The reason wait states are used is because it can take some time for the memory to return read data.  To make up for this delay, you can either slow down the CPU clock or add wait states.  The tradeoff is that the CPU has to wait for the data one way or another.  If you enable wait states, then whenever a memory access is required, the CPU will stall until the request completes, slowing down the overall instruction rate.  However, if no memory operation is taking place, the CPU will run at full speed.  The result is that code will generally execute faster when wait states are enabled.

Comment: Alex, You are saying enabling wait states slows down the overall instruction rate. I agree with that. Then how come data sheets mention 30MHz for 0 wait states and 60MHz for 3 wait states? Your statement indicates that Wait states is inversely proportional to speed but the datasheet specs indicate that wait states is directly proportional to speed. This conflict is what I am trying to struggle with.

Comment: Let's assume the time to complete a memory access is 20 ns.  At 30 MHz, the clock period is 33 ns, so there is enough time to complete the memory access within one clock cycle.  At 60 MHz, the clock period is 17 ns, which is too fast to complete a memory access within one clock cycle.  One wait state means that the CPU 'burns' one clock cycle during every memory access waiting for the memory.  So with 1 wait state at 60 Mhz, the CPU has 33 ns to complete the memory access.

Comment: You can think of the wait state as selectively slowing down the memory access operations so they run at the same speed as the memory, leaving the other operations to run at the core clock speed.  With more wait states and a higher clock speed, the memory operations take the same amount of time, but the other operations are accelerated.

Comment: Alex,Once you trasnlated everything into time units its making sense. Thanks I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

The clock rate of the processor goes up.  The number of useful instructions it can execute *might* go up, down, or stay the same.  It depends on its memory hierarchy or whether and how often it needs to get data off the system bus.  The idea is it might need more wait states at high speed because it cannot guarantee getting the data it needs in time.

So it is all about what you mean by "speed".

Comment: So do I have to interpret that if the MCU runs at higher clock rate it would have to wait for more time to access data from memory? How does clock rate force it to wait for more time when the MCU Flash specs a constant Flash Access time?

Comment: not more time, more wait states.  Each state would be half as long at 60 MHz than at 30 MHz.  Remember that it isn't entirely the Flash Access time that determines how long it takes but also the other things the CPU is doing at the time.

Comment: Sorry crgrace I dint get you. The wait state by definition is a delay experienced by a computer processor when accessing external memory or another device that is slow to respond. My fundamental question is if a processor experiences a delay of 3 wait states how can its speed be at 60MHz versus it experiencing no delay (0 wait state) allow it to be only at 30MHz ? By definition of wait state, it implie that it has the same units as Time.

Comment: Wait states are measured in clock cycles.  So 1 wait state counts for less time at 60 MHz than at 30 MHz.